# How can I different design the text within TextBox (XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

How can I different design the text within the TextBox-Element in XAML

Example: I need the first word normal fontweight and the second word bold...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the WPF RichTextBox control for that.

Example:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="txtRichBox">
                        <FlowDocument>
                            <Paragraph>
                                I am bold inside
                                <Bold>not outside</Bold>
                            </Paragraph>
                        </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

This should create a textbox with content like

**I am bold inside** not outside.

Read more with samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx).

Comment: I didn't know about the relationship between flow docs and RTBs in WPF.  Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

WPF includes a crapton of framework classes for documents.  If you're not looking to *edit* styled text but to *display* it, check out [Flow documents.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx)  If you're looking to edit styled text, then Sizzler's answer is correct.